# Hey ! I used the indicator to indicate that I was turning left

Tags: word-usage, phrases

My mom was driving,when she was going to take the next left,she used her indicator to indicate that. But when she was turning,a car speeded past was while she was turning.(in the direction we were turning.) So she said:

> Hey! I used the indicator to indicate I was turning left.
>
> I gave an indicator to indicate that I was turning left.

What will be a natural way to express this idea? I don't know how this sentence can be spoken naturally in this context....

P.S. She's talking to the driver.

Comment: Who is she talking to? You? The other driver? The police to report a dangerous driver.

Comment: To the driver. (Because she's angry) @James K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> My left turn signal was on!

If you wish to use the word "indicator" I suggest not repeating that in the sentence. Exempli gratia:

> Hey! I used the indicator to show I was turning left.

In my country we're not going to say "indicator."

Comment: In Britain, people commonly say "I indicated left (or right)".